# Is it safe to assume that only iOS versions contain underscore in UserAgent string?

Tags: c#, user-agent

First, I'm getting the userAgent string using the `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent`.

Then, I'm using [us-parser](https://github.com/ua-parser/uap-csharp) C# library to get information about the useragent string. I've noticed that the iOS always has its version written with underscores - "{Major_Minor_Patch}" (e.g. "4_3_3").

I am extracting the version using the: `clientInfo.OS.ToString()`, but it separates major, minor, patch using a "." symbol for all OS ([see source](https://github.com/ua-parser/uap-csharp/blob/master/UAParser/UAParser.cs#L97)). I really need to pass the info about the version with "_" if that's how it is in the useragent.

Two questions:

- is it safe to assume that only iOS versions come with underscores in the userAgent?
- is it safe to assume that all iOS versions come with underscores in the userAgent?

Answer (score 2):

Short answers:

1. No it's not safe to assume only iOS puts underscores in user agent strings. The user agent can be set to almost anything, via plugins for most browsers.
2. Only Apple could answer that with any certainty. Given the answer to 1, I wouldn't depend on it.

Only you can decide if detecting underscores is "good enough" for your purposes. I wouldn't depend on it myself!